# How do I keep "MailApp.sendEmail" emails with the same subject threaded?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've written a script that sends an hourly email to me using:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("john@doe.com", "Status Update", currentStatus);
```

My only gripe is that every message I get is treated as a separate thread, despite the subject lines all being the same. I'd prefer if all were threaded so I can see the stream of messages in one place.

Is there any way to have new status messages appended to the same thread?

Will this require using GMailApp functions instead?

**EDIT (2016-08-26):** I have solved my problem using the following method/workaround:

- Include a unique "marker" somewhere in the status message. I use a static UUID that I generated online.
- Use GmailApp.search() to find the thread with the status message(s) by looking for the unique marker.
- Use GmailApp.reply() to add a new status message to the thread.

This keeps all the status messages together as desired. Perhaps there's a more elegant way to do this but this works...

Comment: You probably need `replyAll` here, cause `reply` replies to the sender (your GAS user email, not recipient) of the thread email. replyAll adds the recipient to cc then